# How to centre a javascript element using inline css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've got some javascript code that I want centring on my webpage, if I enclose it with `<div align="center">` then it works perfectly, but the validator says its not valid HTML5.

I've tried changing it to "margin: 0 auto;" with no luck. I've also tried using "text-align: center" and that doesn't work either. I've even added 
.center {margin: 0 auto}; to my stylesheet and that doesn't work either.

Just curious why the code won't centre correctly using any of those techniques.

My working code is as follows.

```
<div align="center"> 
<script type="application/javascript">
        var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                                            month   : 5, 
                                            day     : 19,
                                            width   : 300, 
                                            height  : 50,
                                            hideLine: true,
                                            rangeHi :"months"
                                            });
        </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually not super straightforward. You can use `flexbox` which doesn't work on older browsers or use the `position absolute 50% - margin` trick. The latter only works if the width of the `div` is fixed (responsive is ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```css
 .center
        {
            width:300px; /*This is same as Countdown width in your javascript*/
            margin: 0 auto;          
            text-align:center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="center"> 
    <script type="application/javascript">
            var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                                                month   : 5, 
                                                day     : 19,
                                                width   : 300, 
                                                height  : 50,
                                                hideLine: true,
                                                rangeHi :"months"
                                                });
            </script>      
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks, i'd played around with it all for awhile trying to get it to shift to the centre using the html5 way. i was able to do it with images and text but i couldn't get this javascript to centre.

Answer (score 0):

try `.center{margin:auto;}`

you may also have to set the width property like `.center{width:50px;margin:auto;}`

Comment: thanks, this one worked too.